# HTTPWebRequest not respecting timeout values

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest

Right now I have some code that is making a web request that looks like the following:

```
internal async static Task<string> MakeWebRequest(string uri)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Timeout = TimeoutInMilliseconds;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = TimeoutInMilliseconds;
        request.Method = "GET";

        var response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        return NonClosingStreamReader.StreamToString(response.GetResponseStream());
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
        {
            MyLogger("Timeout happened");
            return null;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

`TimeOutInMilliSeconds` is set to 50, so I would think that anything that doesn't respond in less than 50 ms would be timed out.  To test this I am making calls against a local python flask app that does the following:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 'I waited 5 seconds!!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My C# code isn't timing out, I'm seeing the "I waited 5 seconds!!" response (and the 5 second wait is very noticeable so I'm sure the python code is doing what I want it to).  Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT** If I make `MakeWebRequest` a synchronous call and use `response.GetResponse()` instead I do see the expected timeout exceptions.  What's the proper way to do this within an async task?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 the Remarks says a DNS lookup itself may take long - have you checked the request to see what takes long?

Comment: @xxbbcc I can't imagine a DNS lookup would take long it's just going to my localhost for the flask app

Comment: I think 50 ms for a timeout is way too low but MSDN specifically mentions the DNS lookup - I think the timeout is only considered starting with the end of the (internal) DNS lookup, not from when you call GetResponseStream(). Don't quote me on this, though. :)

Comment: Regardless if 50 ms is too low it doesn't answer the question.  I've found that if you do the call synchronously it does honor the timeouts (I've modified the question).  Clearly this is not the proper way to do it within an aysnc task